# Google SEO Title & Meta Description

Tags: html, seo, sitemap

My company's web app is using Ruby on Rails and am trying to improve the SEO for the website. Currently, google shows two different set of results (Title & Meta Description).

It will show the correct result that can be found in my source code, in the file application.html.erb.

But sometimes it will show an "incorrect" result that cannot be found at all in my source code, meaning the title and meta description shown cannot be found at all in my source code. 
It used to be there but it has been replaced with new title and meta tag 6 months ago.

- How can I make sure Google does not show title and meta tags that has been replaced and no longer in my source code?
- What changes should I make to my title and meta tags?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Google search console](https://search.google.com/search-console) to verify problems with your site.

Also you can request Google to crawl your page, in order for your changes to be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Google chooses it's own meta description if your Click Thru Rate is lower than they expect or if they don't fit their criteria.

Meta Titles should be 60 characters or less

Meta Descriptions should be 150 characters or less

Are you already in compliance for the above?